# Using partition of unity to glue locally defined functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be bounded set with smooth boundary $\partial U$. Cover $\partial U$ with finitely many open balls $B_i=B(x_i, r_i)$. Suppose I have smooth functions $f_i$ defined on these balls s.t. $f_i=0$ in $B_i\cap\partial U$ and $f>0$ in $B_i\cap U$. I want to construct function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f=0$ in $\partial U$, $f>0$ in $U$ and $f<0$ in $\bar{U}^{c}$.

I was thinking about covering $\bar{U}$ with the balls $B_i$ and $U$ itself and use smooth partition of unity $\zeta_i$, $$\bar{U}\subset\bigcup_{i=0}^nV_i,$$ where $V_0=U$ and $V_i=B_i$, $i=1, \dotso, n$. If I set $f_0=1$, I could define $f=\sum_{i=0}^n\zeta_if_i$. But I'm not sure if this function fulfills the properties I want. And why this sum is even defined because the functions $f_i$ are only locally defined. I'm a little bit confused about the whole concept of partition of unity, so I would be very happy if someone explained it to me, perhaps with examples.

Comment: The functions $f_i$ are only locally defined, but $\zeta_i$ is zero in the places where $f_i$ is not defined. So extending $\zeta_if_i$ to be zero outside of the domain of $f_i$ results in well defined continuous function. Note however that you still need to do some things to have $>0$ everywhere on the inside of $U$ and $<0$ on the outside.

Comment: oh, thanks, I didn't even think about the obvious zero extension..